# Angular 17 - Trigger recurrent polling whenever a boolean variable becomes true and as long as it remains so

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, polling

The situation is as follows:
I have a websocket for communication between app and server. If the websocket were to break I would like to enable backup long polling until the websocket becomes active again.

I thought of creating a Signal boolean that changes state based on the connection/disconnection of the WS. If the WS is active I set the signal to true otherwise to false.

```
 WSStatus = signal(false);
```

```
 WS is up: this.WSStatus(true)
 WS go down: this.WSStatus(false)
```

I thought about doing something like this, but takeUntil waits for an Observable and I was unable to replace the Signal operation with an Observable

```
 this.startPolling(5000).pipe(takeUntil(!this.WSStatus())).subscribe()
```

```
 startPolling(interval: number = 5000): Observable<string> {
  
    return timer(0, interval)
      .pipe(
        switchMap( () => { return this.myHttpRequest() })
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the code is to have a backup to the websocket in case of problems, so when it is NOT active I run a long time polling on http protocol until the websocket becomes active again

**This is the solution I found:**

properties:

```
pollingDone = signal(false)
private timerDone$ = new Subject<boolean>();
```

ws connection:

```
...
openObserver: {
  next: (event) => {
    this.pollingDone.set(true);
  }
},
closeObserver: {
  next: (event) => {
    this.pollingDone.set(false);
  }
}
...
```

constructor

```
effect( () => {
  this.timerDone$.next(this.pollingDone())
  if(this.pollingDone() === false) {
    this.startPolling(5000).subscribe(val => this.store.dispatch(TablePageActions.load()))
  }
})
```

methods

```
startPolling(interval: number = 5000): Observable<any> {
  return timer(0, interval)
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.timerDone$)
  )
}
```

Maybe it's not stylistic, I had difficulty defining an observable boolean accepted by the takeUntil, anyway it seems the goal was achieved. I tried to hook directly into the openObserver and closeObserver Events but failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Angular signal withing RxJS chain you need to convert it into Observable using [`toObservable`](https://angular.io/api/core/rxjs-interop/toObservable) provided by `@angular/core/rxjs-interop`:

Then you can use it within `takeUntil()`

```
takeUntil(toObservable(this.WSStatus))
```

Note, that you might need to provide Injector yourself because `toObservable` uses `inject(Injector)` by default which is I think available only in components constructor.

Comment: Not so easy, boolean Signal converted to Observable is not accepted from takeUntil. I find the solution, I'll post a replay to my message

Comment: That's not true. `takeUntil()` accepts Observables and even Promises. There's no difference between an Observable created using `toObservable()` or any other way. The Observable passed to  `takeUntil()` can emit any `next` value or just `complete`.

Comment: I wouldn't know what to answer, I don't have much experience and simply converting the Signal I couldn't, I don't exclude I had introduced other problems at that time.  In any case, thank you for your help